# Some sql query to fetch data not having relation

Tags: mysql, sql

There are three tables 'users', 'groups' 'users_groups' The relation between users and groups table is many to many and users_groups stores that relation.

```
 users        users_groups                             groups
 -id (pk)     -user_id(fk references users)            -id (pk)
 -username    -group_id (fk references groups)         -name
 -password
```

Data:

```
users
1. abc
2. admin
3. user
4. tester

Groups
1. testgroup
2. newgroup

Users_groups
group_id    user_id
   1           1
   1           2
```

Lets say we are on group 1 (testgroup) page. I want to fetch all the users which does not belong to this group. How can I do this? If its possible i want to perform this with one sql query

Update

```
SELECT u.username, g.name
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN groups_users ug ON u.id = ug.user_id
LEFT JOIN groups g ON g.id = ug.group_id
WHERE g.id !=1 OR g.id IS NULL
```

Comment: so this aint technical question. i asked which i could not solved. isnt this forum about asking stuffs which u have difficult solving

Comment: At least have a go. Either you are learning SQL (in which case it is a good exercise to have a go) *OR* you are a person working that is experiencing a difficult. In either case you would have a bit of SQL to including in the OP.

Comment: i have tried but could not solve. should have included what i tried. I agree to that but dont come up with comments showing ur arrogance and being condescending

Comment: Next time post what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple query:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.id not in (select user_id from user_groups ug where group_id = 1)
```

If you want to reference by name instead of number:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.id not in (select user_id
                   from user_groups ug join
                        groups g
                        on ug.group_id = g.id
                   where g.name = 'testgroup'
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.username FROM
users u
LEFT JOIN
    users_groups ug ON u.id = ug.user_id,
    groups g ON g.group_id = ug.group_id

WHERE g.name != 'testgroup'
GROUP BY u.username
```

Comment: groups g ON g.user_id, but i dont have user_id column in groups table